# ASP.NET MVC: Authenticating a user without creating the user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am creating an MVC 5 application that authenticates a user via Facebook to access a particular resource.

I want to be able to authenticate this user with a cookie as if they are logged into my site as an authenticated user manually.

However, it is a requirement that this user not be actually created as a user in the membership system used by the site, as it is reserved for admins.

Is this possible?

I attempted to do this by creating an identity manually but this was a total hack attempt by piecing together the existing code from the MVC Account controller...

```
var authUser = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = me.email, Email = me.email };
var manager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
manager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
manager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().CreateIdentityAsync(authUser, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie));
```

It almost seems to work, but then it complains that the user id does not exist.

Which I assume means it's attempting to use my user database to authenticate the user, which as I said is not what we want.

So is it possible to manually authenticate a user with the custom default asp.net account implementation and persist an authenticated cookie, but NOT create an actual user?

please let me know what more info I could provide to help find a solution. thank you

Answer (score 0):

shortly after submitting this I found this question: [Storing/Retrieving user data without database when using OWIN cookie authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320632/storing-retrieving-user-data-without-database-when-using-owin-cookie-authenticat)

which seems to do exactly what I need, indeed this did the trick, thanks and sorry for duplicating the question